# Standard for representing a float scaled to a particular range?

Tags: floating-point, binary

**TL;DR Is there a "standard" way to represent a float scaled to a particular range, such that we get maximum precision for the given bit depth, within that range?**

I'll start with my general question, and because StackExchange likes me to be specific about what I am trying to do, I shall end with specifics.

#### General Question

From wikipedia; *"All integers with 7 or fewer decimal digits, and any 2<sup>n</sup> for a whole number −149 ≤ n ≤ 127, can be converted exactly into an IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point value"*

The above seems to read as follows: I could store 193.125672, because 193 is a whole number between 2<sup>-149</sup> and 2<sup>127</sup>, and .125672 has fewer than 7 decimal digits.

**Question 1**: Have I misunderstood this? Surely it doesn't mean 2<sup>n</sup> where n is between -149 and 127, because those numbers are enormous and could not be represented by a 32 bit value?

**Question 2**: What if I want to store a number with much more decimal point precision, at the expense of the number's "height" (i.e. how big the whole-number-portion of the value is)? According to my reading, that's not covered by this IEEE 754 standard. Is there a variant of this standard that can do this? Is there some other standard that "goes to more decimal points", or do other standards go higher with fewer decimal points? Or perhaps there is some standard for how I might encode the "decimal point length" and "height" of the value? To put the latter in another way, a standard for dynamically specifying the range of the value we are representing? Or is it considered "standard" to just increase the bit depth until you achieve the precision required?

Taking a simple example, let's say I would like to store a value from 0 to 1 to the best possible accuracy within 32 bits, then I am essentially able to store a number to the nearest 1/(2<sup>32</sup>-1).

I understand that I can do the above by simply storing or transferring the 32 bit binary number, and just *knowing* that it represents something between 0 and 1. My question is about whether there's some standard for "*knowing it represents something between 0 and 1*". Or whether there is indeed some way of encoding this fact.

If not, who decreed this rule of 7 digits of decimal accuracy, and on what grounds? (/mock indignance)

#### Specifics

I would like to send a reading from a 24 bit ADC, where input is between 0 and 3.3. I understand I can represent my ADC's input voltage to the nearest (3.3 / (2<sup>24</sup> - 1))V. I want to send the reading to a recipient in a sensible or standard way, if such a thing exists and, of course, without losing resolution.

Should I;
a) send the 24 bit binary number and tell the person separately that it represents some value between 0 and 3.3? They will need to do the rest.

b) send the value as a 32 bit binary number and tell them "it is an xyz standard float and you need to scale it"

Comment: (Q1: You misunderstood that. It means *exactly* that, and there is no problem at all storing an $n, -128 \le n \le127$ *in some part* of 32 bits. And it does not read *integral parts*, but `integers`.)